# How to display owner of a post in laravel admin list display?

Tags: laravel

```
public function index()
{
    $query = Activity::orderBy('id','DESC')->with('provinces');
    if(!Auth::user()->hasRole('Administer')){
        $query=$query->where('province_id', Auth::user()->id);
    }
    $activities = $query->latest()->get();

    return view('activity.index',compact('activities'));
}
```

How to display owner of a post in laravel admin list display?

My User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia
{
    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Activity::class);
    }
}
```

My Activity Model:

```
class Activity extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function provinces()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Province::class);
    }
}
```

My province Model

```
class Province extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [ 'title',  'post_id'];

    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Activity::class);
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

I want to show the content to the user by province.
And also the admin can see all the content.
please help me i am new in laravel

Comment: Please add your models.

Comment: Ali Farhoudi i added my model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you should change your province conditions to:

```
if (!Auth::user()->hasRole('Administer')) {
    $query = $query->where('province_id', Auth::user()->province_id);
}
```

You have defined that each activity belongs to an user. So can access owner of each activity like this:

```
$activity->user->name;
```

And if your activity belongs to a province, you should define your relation in this way:

```
class Activity extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function province()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Province::class);
    }
}
```

Also for your `Province` model:

```
class Province extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [ 'title',  'post_id'];

    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Activity::class);
    }
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

And this is best practice to use **eager loading** for fetching related records. It will look like this one:

```
$query = Activity::with(['user', 'province'])->orderBy('id','DESC');
```

Also another hint: try to use better variable names. You can use `$activities` instead of `$query`.

Comment: Could you please describe realations between your models? Because I think you have problem in realation definition.

Comment: Mr. Farhudi Users are registered in my system by province and my activity is also registered by province.
Example: If a user was from Tehran, he could only view Tehran related activity and can't see the other province activity.
Thanks for helping me

Comment: yeah i can describe relations between my models i don't have problem in describe relations. I just want to show the activities by province.
And the user can only see activity related to his province.and Admin can see all activity.

Comment: Just changed my answer based on your comment